# Formatting large numbers in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, formatting

I am using Unity to make an "Incremental Game" also known as an "Idle Game" and I am trying to format large numbers. For example, when `gold` gets to say 1000 or more, it will display as `Gold: 1k` instead of `Gold: 1000`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour {

    public UnityEngine.UI.Text GoldDisplay;
    public UnityEngine.UI.Text GPC;
    public double gold = 0.0;
    public int gpc = 1;

    void Update(){
        GoldDisplay.text = "Gold: " +  gold.ToString ("#,#");
        //Following is attempt at changing 10,000,000 to 10.0M
        if (gold >= 10000000) {
        GoldDisplay.text = "Gold: " + gold.ToString ("#,#M");
        }
        GPC.text = "GPC: " + gpc;
    }

    public void Clicked(){
            gold += gpc;
    }
}
```

I have tried other examples while searching online, which is where `gold.ToString ("#,#");` came from, however none of them worked.

Comment: `gold.ToString` returns a result, it does not modify `gold`. You need to do something like `GoldDisplay.text = "Gold: " + gold.ToString("#,#");`

Comment: How big will this gold number get to? Say Quadrillions?

Comment: But you're going to have problems using `int` for an idle game. The max value is 2 billion.

Comment: same with float, some idle game have issue with it, go with double

Comment: @Zze Yes, very big numbers, probably a max of 10x1^20 but I can work out a hard max.

Comment: 1^20 is approximately 1. 10x1 would be in the neighborhood of 10. Pretty big numbers, eh? Or is your operator precedence as uncommon as SQL Server's?

Comment: @Fredou double, or ulong?

Comment: You could override the `ToString()` and create the method to do it manually.

Comment: @Zze double can go to 1.7976931348623157E+308 and ulong to  18,446,744,073,709,551,615 with idle game so far i always saw bug when people was using something else than double. like achievement impossible to get or bonus. higher is better

Comment: [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can handle 10.

Comment: So iv'e updated the code according to your feedback, the code works now, however 10,000,000 comes out as 10,000,000M and not 10.0M

Comment: I rolled back your edit so that the question still has the original code, rather than the fixed code. If you edit your question to fix your code when you get an answer, it looks strange when the answers are referring to previous code.

Comment: If you like, you can answer your own question with the code that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this method in my project, you can use too. Maybe there is better way, I dont know.

```
public void KMBMaker( Text txt, double num )
    {
        if( num < 1000 )
        {
            double numStr = num;
            txt.text = numStr.ToString() + "";
        }
        else if( num < 1000000 )
        {
            double numStr = num/1000;
            txt.text = numStr.ToString() + "K";
        }
        else if( num < 1000000000 )
        {
            double numStr = num/1000000;
            txt.text = numStr.ToString() + "M";
        }
        else
        {
            double numStr = num/1000000000;
            txt.text = numStr.ToString() + "B";
        }
    }
```

and use this method in your update like this.

```
void Update()
{
     KMBMaker( GoldDisplay.text, gold );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Slight refactoring:

```
public static string KMBMaker( double num )
{
    double numStr;
    string suffix;
    if( num < 1000d )
    {
        numStr = num;
        suffix = "";
    }
    else if( num < 1000000d )
    {
        numStr = num/1000d;
        suffix = "K";
    }
    else if( num < 1000000000d )
    {
        numStr = num/1000000d;
        suffix = "M";
    }
    else
    {
        numStr = num/1000000000d;
        suffix = "B";
    }
    return numStr.ToString() + suffix;
}
```

Use:

```
GoldDisplay.text = KMBMaker(gold);
```

Changes:

1. Explicitly use `double` constants
2. Remove duplication
3. Separate concerns - there's no need for this method to know about text boxes

Comment: Tip for people that hate to count 0's like I do and/or want to go into even bigger suffixes. The values can also be replaced with scientific notation, aka 1000 = 1e3d  1000000 = 1e6d and so on

Answer (score 4):

i don't think there is a build-in method for that so i just maybe reinvented the wheel by writing my own way but this should be how i would maybe do it

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (double i = 500d; i < 5e23; i *= 100d)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i.ToMyNumber());
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

    }

    public static class helper
    {
        private static readonly  List<string> myNum;

        static helper()
        {
            myNum = new List<string>();
            myNum.Add("");
            myNum.Add("kilo");
            myNum.Add("mill");
            myNum.Add("bill");
            myNum.Add("tril");
            myNum.Add("quad");
            myNum.Add("quin");
            myNum.Add("sext");
            // ....
        }

        public static string ToMyNumber(this double value)
        {
            string initValue = value.ToString();
            int num = 0;
            while (value >= 1000d)
            {
                num++;
                value /= 1000d;
            }

            return string.Format("{0} {1} ({2})", value, myNum[num], initValue);
        }
    }
}
```

which print this

```
500  (500)
50 kilo (50000)
5 mill (5000000)
500 mill (500000000)
50 bill (50000000000)
5 tril (5000000000000)
500 tril (500000000000000)
50 quad (5E+16)
5 quin (5E+18)
500 quin (5E+20)
50 sext (5E+22)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
    private static List<string> nFormat= new List<string>();

        void Awake()
        {
         nFormat.Add("");
         nFormat.Add("K");
         nFormat.Add("M");
         nFormat.Add("B");
        //...
        }

        public static string Double2dec(double value)
        {
             int num = 0;
             while (value >= 1000d)
             {
                 num++;
                 value /= 1000d;
             }
             return value.ToString("F2") + nFormat[num];
        }
```

Comment: This one is the closest to what I would use. Though I'm said no one is utilizing logarithms...

Answer (score 0):

I tried some of the solutions given here, but was put off by the effort it would need to write down all abbreviations from K to NoNod, so I wrote this - though I haven't tried whether it impacts performance greatly (though it seemed to work as smooth as using scientific notation).

```
using System;
//System.Numerics necessary for us of BigInteger only - alternatively use double (which might be faster, but more inaccurate
using System.Numerics;

namespace WPF_Clicker
{
    public static class NumberFormatter
    {
        
        /*NumberFormat
         * Scientific   => 0.0e0 | example: 1.234e14    -> 123,400,000,000,000
         * Abbreviation  => 0.0xx | example: 123.4T      -> 123,400,000,000,000
        */
        public enum NumberFormat
        {
            Scientific,
            Abbreviation
        }
        
        public static string FormatNumber(BigInteger number, NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.Scientific)
        {
            if (format == NumberFormat.Scientific)
                return ScientificFomat(number);
            else
                return AbbreviationFormat(number);
        }

        public static string ScientificFomat(BigInteger number)
        {
            if (number < 1000)
                //if number smaller than 1,000, don't use special format
                return number.ToString("#.##0");
            else
                //return number as scientific notation with 1 place before and 3 places after decimal point
                return number.ToString("e3");
        }

        public static string AbbreviationFormat(BigInteger number)
        {
            if (number < 1000)
                //if number smaller than 1,000, don't use special format
                return number.ToString("#.##0");

            //get division of number (string length - 1) by 3 and get remainder -> appendix changes with every 4 characters
            int decider = Math.DivRem(number.ToString().Length - 1, 3, out int remainder) - 1;
            //if decider is bigger than 9, looping for every place of the decider number
            int declength = decider.ToString().Length;
            //string is necessary to decide on which appendix to use
            string decstring = decider.ToString();
            //string for the appendix
            string appendix = "";

            if (decider > 99)
                //return "infinity" if decider is greater than 99
                //can be changed if you decide to go over NoNod (decider > 99)
                return "infinity";
            else
            {
                //thousands, millions and billions are special cases
                if (decider < 3)
                {
                    if (decider == 0)
                        appendix = "K";
                    else if (decider == 1)
                        appendix = "M";
                    else if (decider == 2)
                        appendix = "B";
                    else
                        appendix = "";
                }
                else
                    //loop through for decider number string
                    //start at the last place, since these will be definite and it saves the check of whether there is more than 1 place in the decider number string
                    for (int counter = declength - 1; counter >= 0; counter--)
                    {
                        char decchar = decstring[counter];

                        //handle last place of decider number string
                        if (counter == declength - 1)
                            if (decchar == '1')
                                appendix = "U";
                            else if (decchar == '2')
                                appendix = "D";
                            else if (decchar == '3')
                                appendix = "T";
                            else if (decchar == '4')
                                appendix = "Qa";
                            else if (decchar == '5')
                                appendix = "Qi";
                            else if (decchar == '6')
                                appendix = "Sx";
                            else if (decchar == '7')
                                appendix = "Sp";
                            else if (decchar == '8')
                                appendix = "Oc";
                            else if (decchar == '9')
                                appendix = "No";
                            else
                                appendix = "";
                        else
                        //handles second place (or higher) of decider number string
                        {
                            if (decchar == '1')
                                appendix += "Dc";
                            else if (decchar == '2')
                                appendix += "Vg";
                            else if (decchar == '3')
                                appendix += "Td";
                            else if (decchar == '4')
                                appendix += "Qad";
                            else if (decchar == '5')
                                appendix += "Qid";
                            else if (decchar == '6')
                                appendix += "Sxd";
                            else if (decchar == '7')
                                appendix += "Spd";
                            else if (decchar == '8')
                                appendix += "Ocd";
                            else if (decchar == '9')
                                appendix += "Nod";
                        }
                    }

                //since the number string is at this point definitly more than 3 places long, use the remainder to set the decimal point
                string numberstr = number.ToString().Substring(0, 4).Insert(remainder + 1, ",");

                //put the number with decimal point together with the appendix | example: 123,456,789,012,345,678,901,234,567,890,123,456,789,012 -> 123,4DDc
                return numberstr + appendix;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.